# Rotation - slowing it down using willAnimateSecondHalfOfRotationFromInterfaceOrientation

Tags: iphone, rotation, orientation

people, how do you actually slow down the orientation-rotation when using the  **"willAnimateSecondHalfOfRotationFromInterfaceOrientation:"** method?

I currently have this:

```
-(void) willAnimateSecondHalfOfRotationFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation 
                                                       duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    [self positionViews];
}
```

And I understand that this "willAnimate2ndHalf..." method gets called automatically when the rotation does indeed happen - well where do I actually get to change its DURATION value?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the overall timing of he app's rotation, it can't be done. willAnimateSecondHalfOfRotationFromInterfaceOrientation is meant for adding custom code, like setting custom coordinates, properties, things like that.

Comment: well there's gotta be SOME way to slow-down or speed-up the rotation - otherwise there wouldn't be a "duration" argument for the method. In the official Apple docs, it says: "Parameters
fromInterfaceOrientation:
The state of the application’s user interface orientation before the rotation. The possible values are described in UIInterfaceOrientation.
duration:
The duration of the second half of the pending rotation, measured in seconds."  So, it seems like a duration value can be provided, and it could either be high or low - fast or slow, don't you agree?

Comment: Yes you can, if you were calling this method. However, if you're taking about rotating the device, this is called automatically (by UIApplication, I believe) and you do not have access to the call properties. What you can do is turn off auto-rotation for all on-screen objects and implement your own method, listening for the UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification. Then you will have to manually animate and position your objects for the rotation. Really, you're reinventing the wheel here.